# WKInterfaceMap Never Loads

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, watchkit

I'm having an issue with WKInterfaceMap.  I'm trying to just show a simple map with a simple annotation, but it constantly reloads.  I'm using Xcode 7 beta, and I've already tried:

- Deleting Derived Data
- Restarting Xcode
- Clean Project
- Reset both simulators
- Compiled on different computer

All with no luck.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so maybe someone can help me out here.

Here's my code where I load the map and add annotation.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    NSArray *data = (NSArray *)context;
    self.latitude = [(NSNumber *)[data objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    self.longitude = [(NSNumber *)[data objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    self.latitudeDelta = [(NSNumber *)[data objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    self.longitudeDelta = [(NSNumber *)[data objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(loc, span);

    [self.map setRegion:region];
    [self.map addAnnotation:loc withPinColor:WKInterfaceMapPinColorPurple];
}
```

I've already checked and made sure my latitude, longitude, and deltas are all correct by printing them out (and I've tried using set values as well), so I know it's not that.

I can't post a picture because I'm new here but it's just the reloading icon.

If any of you could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try moving your map code to `willActivate` that worked for me.

Comment: still not working in beta2 and beta3

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem where the map would not show on the watch in the simulator.  My solution was:

1) CMD + Shift to go to the home screen and open the maps app on the iPhone Simulator

2) CMD + Shift to go to the home screen then CMD + Shift to see the apps and open the maps app on the Watch

3) I just waited for it to load up and once it did on both simulated devices, I re-ran my app.  It worked fine after that.

Not sure why this works, but others have found this to work for them to.

Reference: [How to get a map view in watchOS 2.0](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6310)